# How to display CPP, Java or any other programming language codes in proper format in html page?

Tags: html, web, web-applications, blogger

I want to write codes in proper format in a blog as [Sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeWU9.png)

How it can be done? Is there any plugin that I need to install?

Comment: You can use `<code>` tag, but it won't add the line number or anything as in the image, that you need to create a custom component and use it anywhere you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Plugin" from Google called code pretiffier. First of all import the following script into your website:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

After you imported this, you can write the wished code into a pre tag with the class "prettyprint". It should look like this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
   //Your custom code
</pre>
```